# cannot access members of tuple in future builder in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, tuples

I have a Tuple which has two members: `List<DeliveryAddressModel>` and `ApiResponseCode`. The code is as follows:

```
  Future<Tuple2<List<DeliveryAddressModel>, ApiResponseCode>> getAddressList() async {
    int retry = 0;
    List<DeliveryAddressModel> deliveryAddressList = [];
    while (retry++ < 2) {
      try {
        deliveryAddressList =
            await CoreRepo.instance.getCoreClient().getDeliveryAddresses();

        for (int i = 0; i < deliveryAddressList.length; i++) {
          print("inside core repo: ${deliveryAddressList[i].addressTitle}");
        }
        return Tuple2(deliveryAddressList, ApiResponseCode.SUCCESS);
      } catch (e) {
        CoreRepo.instance.getCoreClient().getDeliveryAddresses();
      }
    }
    return Tuple2(deliveryAddressList, ApiResponseCode.SERVER_ERROR);
  }
```

Now inside some other page I need to show the data, more specifically `List<DeliveryAddressModel>`.

So this is what I tried:

```
  body: FutureBuilder(
    future: CoreRepo.instance.getAddressList(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.data == null) {
        return LoadingWidget(
          status: "Loading your delivery addresses",
        );
      }
      if (snapshot.data.item2 == ApiResponseCode.FAILED) { ========> ERROR 1
        return Text("Failed");
      }
      return RefreshIndicator(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        child: buildFeed(snapshot.data.item1), ========> ERROR 1
        onRefresh: () => refreshList(context),
      );
    },
  ),
```

**ERROR 1:**

`The property 'item2' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'.`

`Try making the access conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!').`

This comes straight from the documentation of [tuple](https://pub.dev/packages/tuple):

> const t = Tuple2<String, int>('a', 10);
>
> print(t.item1); // prints 'a' print(t.item2); // prints '10'

For more info: [core_repo](https://pastebin.com/cakCSrbq), [core_client](https://pastebin.com/7LgbNt0G), [delivery_list_page](https://pastebin.com/FHDaXU2X)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the snapshot data itself could be null you should safely access its value

```dart
snapshot.data?.item2
```

Also you need modify future builder

```dart
FutureBuilder<Tuple2<List<DeliveryAddressModel>, ApiResponseCode>>>
```

because future builder can not infer the data type you should provide it your self

Comment: Yeah I tried that, but it gives me `The getter 'item2' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.`

Comment: I edited my answer I hope it solves your issue

Answer (score 0):

Use this flow so I think solved the problem.
The property 'item2' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'.

Try making the access conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!').

Comment: I know the error. I was asking for a solution